# MySQL - Optimizing a large table's join

Tags: mysql, query-performance, join

Im using the following query. This eat my complete CPU in Aurora Cluster. Also too much of wait. I tried by tunning index, but still no luck. Is there any recommendation to make it perform better?

#### Query:

```sql
SELECT `r` . `id`,
       `r` . `name`,
       `r` . `dob`,
       `r` . `gender`,
       `r` . `photo_show`,
       `p` . `user_id`,
       `p` . `stateother`,
       `p` . `districtother`,
       `p` . `cityother`,
       `p` . `occupation`,
       `p` . `qualification`,
       `p` . `country`,
       'success'
       AS `success`,
       `verified_photo`
       AS `view_photo`,
       CASE
         WHEN `r` . `marital_status` = 1 THEN 'Never Married'
         WHEN `r` . `marital_status` = 2 THEN 'Widowed'
         WHEN `r` . `marital_status` = 3 THEN 'Divorced'
         WHEN `r` . `marital_status` = 4 THEN 'Awaiting divorce'
         WHEN `r` . `marital_status` = 5 THEN 'Not-Specified'
         ELSE ''
       end
       AS `marital_status_name`,
       r.`paid_amnt`,
       IF (`p` . `country` > 0, (SELECT co . `english`
                                 FROM   `country` co
                                 WHERE  co . id = `p` . `country`), `p` . `country`
       )    AS
       `country_name`,
       IF (`p` . `state` > 0, (SELECT st . `english`
                               FROM   `state` st
                               WHERE  st . id = `p` . `state`), `p` . `state`)
       AS
       `state_name`,
       IF (`p` . `district` > 0, (SELECT dt . `english`
                                  FROM   `district` dt
                                  WHERE  dt . id = `p` . `district`), `p` .
       `district`) AS
       `district_name`,
       IF (`p` . `city` > 0, (SELECT ct . `english`
                              FROM   `city` ct
                              WHERE  ct . id = `p` . `city`), `p` . `city`)
       AS `city_name`,
       IF (`p` . `qualification` > 0, (SELECT pqu . `english`
                                       FROM   `qualification` pqu
                                       WHERE  pqu . id = `p` . `qualification`),
       `p` .
       `qualification`)
       AS `qualification_name`,
       IF (`p` . `occupation` > 0, (SELECT oc . `english`
                                    FROM   `occupation` oc
                                    WHERE  oc . id = `p` . `occupation`), `p` .
       `occupation`)
       AS `occupation_name`,
       IF (vbe . id > 0, 1, 0)
       AS `viewed_or_not`,
       IF (r . `verified_photo` != '', 1, 0)
       AS `photo_uploaded_ro_not`
FROM   `register` r
       JOIN `profile` `p`
         ON `r` . `id` = `p` . `user_id`
       JOIN `types_preference` `cp`
         ON `cp`.`userid` = `r`.`id`
       LEFT JOIN `viewed_by_me` vbe
              ON vbe . userid = 123123
                 AND r . `id` = vbe . `viewid`
WHERE  `cp`.`castid` = 451
       AND EXISTS (SELECT `r`.`types`
                   FROM   `types_preference` `cpre`
                   WHERE  `r`.`types` = `cpre`.`castid`
                          AND `cpre`.`userid` = 123123)
       AND 1
       AND ( 1 )
       AND ( `r` . `dob` BETWEEN '1995-09-23' AND '2005-09-23' )
       AND `r`.`id` NOT IN ( 11111 )
       AND r.`religion` = 1
       AND r.`gender` = 2
       AND r.`is_delete` = 0
       AND `r`.`is_verify` = 1
GROUP  BY `r`.`id`
ORDER  BY `viewed_or_not` ASC,
          `photo_uploaded_ro_not` DESC,
          `verify_date` DESC
LIMIT  15 offset 0
```

#### Explain:

[image]

#### MySQL Performance:

[image]

Total Rows in register table: 643457

#### Table DDL: https://pastebin.com/mSCqxefq

#### Table status: https://pastebin.com/nRa70Jqh

#### Server details:

Its AWS Aurora with 5.7
8 core CPU
64GB memory
SSD with high IOPS(it can scale to any limit)

The number of tables 450.

Comment: @TheDataGuy     Could you post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name; for the 3 tables - register, profile, types_preference?  And the TEXT results of SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE 'table_name';  for your 3 tables  for analysis,  What is typical ROWS SENT count at completion of the query?

Comment: @WilsonHauck add the details and updated the question

Comment: A) What is the typical rows count of delivered results?  B)  Will your results change significantly if you remove the line  
           AND `r`.`id` NOT IN ( 11111 )  
from the query?  This is likely causing a TABLE SCAN.

Comment: A) Max results would be 1k or less than that B)no frequent changes, I checked the query plan by removing the `r.id NOT IN` but no changes in the query plan, with `NOT IN` its a range scan, without that index scan. Range scan gives lesser rows estimate.

Comment: Please post TEXT results of the EXPLAIN report when you run without the r.id NOT IN,

Comment: Added the query plan here - https://pastes.io/dtbvqhcnij

Comment: For your register table, A) INX_dob is a redundant index, and should be removed B) within INX_multi you have 'id', is an unnecessary element because with MySQL the primary ID always is a part of the available data behind the scenes,

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
AND very helpful OS information, includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Unfortunatly Im not an authorized person to share the global status and full processlist.

Comment: When your situation changes, consider the possibility of improving the performance of the server.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have a column for each language, have a row for each.  And a column for `language`.

In `EXISTS`, don't select a column.  (The standard pattern is just `1`.)  Change

```
AND EXISTS (SELECT `r`.`types` FROM ... )
```

to

```
AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM ... )
```

Boolean expressions return 0 for false and 1 for true, for example:

```
IF (vbe . id > 0, 1, 0) AS `viewed_or_not`
```

can be simplified to

```
vbe.id > 0 AS `viewed_or_not`
```

These Indexes may help with performance:

```
register:  INDEX(is_verify, is_delete, gender,
                 religion, types, paid_amnt, id)
types_preference:  INDEX(castid, userid)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, just a clarification, not able to understand this `In EXISTS, don't select a column. (The standard pattern is just 1.)` Or not sure where to fit this

Comment: @TheDataGuy - I  changed my Answer to give the context.  (It is not critical to fix it.)

Comment: Great, is there any reason to have index on register table in the reverse order? because in select it'll be like `religion, gender, is_delete, is_verify`

Comment: @TheDataGuy - The order of things AND'd in the `WHERE` does not matter.  More: [_Index Cookbook_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)